# ManyToMany mapping to include some extra records

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have following model:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    ...

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Permission> allowedPermissions;

    ...

}



@Entity
public class Permission {

    ...

    private boolean isDefault;

    ...

}
```

Is it possible to map `User.allowedPermissions` so that it contains both `Permissions` that are connected to the `User` and also these with `isDefault = true` but are not explicitly connected?

I use Hibernate as Jpa provider.

Comment: On creating a user you could add the default permissions to any explicitly selected so that they will then exist in the join table.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would not be possible because you don't have enough information about Permissions in the User.

If you think at a many-to-many relationship, on the database it's a relation table between two other tables.

Now, in your User entity you're correctly using a Set to see all the relations stored in this cross table (let's say user_permission). But at this level you're not able to know the default permissions, that can be retrieved via a PermissionDAO very easily (I assume you're using a DAO/Service design, if not adjust it to your needs).

If you want a superset (allowedPermissions + defaultPermissions), then you can maybe write a utility method at service layer if you like:

```
getAllPermissions(User user) {
   return userDAO.getAllowedPermissions(user).addAll(permissionDAO.getDefaultPermissions()); 
}
```

Why at service layer? Because you need two DAOs at the same time, and you don't want to inject a DAO into another.
Let me know if this is useful.